# SASS workflow: replacing remote CSS file with SASS-generated local file

Tags: firebug, sass, compass-sass

We design and develop WordPress sites and themes. Myself I do local development using a MAMP setup with a full copy of the remote site. Our designer, however is mostly concerned with editing CSS-files, and having him install a local web server would be overkill. Editing in Firebug + updating the local css + git commit + automatic deployment to staging server was fine until now, but we would like to integrate SASS into our workflow.

We're looking for a solution where he could view the staging site in his browser, but replace the remote CSS with a local one, generated by sass --watch. I have looked around for a browser extension that would allow this, but so far haven't been successful.

What do other people do in a similar situation?

Comment: Overkill? Dunno, MAMP takes what? 5min to set up?  And I can't imagine editing in Firebug being very productive. If it's the database that's the hitch couldn't you tunnel the connection to the server with SSH?

Comment: It's not just installing the server. It's having a synced copy of every one of our sites in development, databases and all. Sure, it's possible, but still a bit over the top when all he needs to do is edit css and image files.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I think you'd have to have some sort of app on the designer's machine that would watch the folder and upload the file to the proper spot.

Another route to explore might be to have the FTP server mounted in the filesystem (on OSX, I'd use Transmit Disk, but there's other solutions) and have Compass compiling to that directory when it's mounted. Not sure if that would work.

How will you maintain sync between his/her CSS work and your git repo?